# Assigning functions to dynamically created buttons in kivy?

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy

I am working on this program in which a list buttons gets created dynamically, based on the items in a list. The code I am using for this is:

````
self.list_of_btns = []

    def create(self, list=items):                                               #Creates Categorie Buttons
        self.h = 1
        for i in list:
            self.h = self.h - 0.2
            self.btn = Button(text= f"{i}", size_hint=(.2,.22), pos_hint={"center_y":self.h, "center_x":.5}) 
            self.list_of_btns.append(self.btn)   
            self.add_widget(self.btn)
```
Now I want to add a function to each button. The function is suppose to write the button name (i) to a .txt file. This part of the code gets handled in an external module. 

The problem I am having rn is i cant bind the buttons to their individual functions. I alwasy get the error File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 238, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: Properties ['command'] passed to __init__ may not be existing property names. Valid properties are ['always_release', 'anchors', 'background_color', 'background_disabled_down', 'background_disabled_normal', 'background_down', 'background_normal', 'base_direction', 'bold', 'border', 'center', 'center_x', 'center_y', 'children', 'cls', 'color', 'disabled', 'disabled_color', 'disabled_image', 'disabled_outline_color', 'ellipsis_options', 'font_blended', 'font_context', 'font_family', 'font_features', 'font_hinting', 'font_kerning', 'font_name', 'font_size', 'halign', 'height', 'ids', 'is_shortened', 'italic', 'last_touch', 'line_height', 'markup', 'max_lines', 'min_state_time', 'mipmap', 'motion_filter', 'opacity', 'outline_color', 'outline_width', 'padding', 'padding_x', 'padding_y', 'parent', 'pos', 'pos_hint', 'refs', 'right', 'shorten', 'shorten_from', 'size', 'size_hint', 'size_hint_max', 'size_hint_max_x', 'size_hint_max_y', 'size_hint_min', 'size_hint_min_x', 'size_hint_min_y', 'size_hint_x', 'size_hint_y', 'split_str', 'state', 'state_image', 'strikethrough', 'strip', 'text', 'text_language', 'text_size', 'texture', 'texture_size', 'top', 'underline', 'unicode_errors', 'valign', 'width', 'x', 'y']
````

Comment: So basically I am unable rn to bind any kind of command to my buttons. Not even a simple print command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.bind() method can be used.  In this example, partial is used in order to preset an argument so that each button does something unique.  self.btn was changed to _btn because the references are being added to a list and self.btn was repeatedly assigned a new object.  I didn't think this was intended, but it is not a critical part of this answer.

The self.h was changed to self.height in the dictionary describing the button because I think that may be the source of the error printed in the question.

```
from functools import partial


self.list_of_btns = []
# EDITED after original posting
def your_function(self, _button, your_argument, *args, **kwargs):
    print(type(self))
    print(type(_button))
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    print(your_argument)

def create(self, list=items):                                               #Creates Categorie Buttons
    self.h = 1
    for i in list:
        self.h = self.h - 0.2
        _btn = Button(text= f"{i}", size_hint=(.2,.22), pos_hint={"center_y":self.height, "center_x":.5})
        myfun = partial(self.your_function, your_argument=i)
        # this should be a function, not function()
        _btn.bind(on_press=myfun)
        self.list_of_btns.append(_btn)
        self.add_widget(_btn)
```

Comment: This does seem to work in part since the error message changed. But I am now bring told "got multiple values for argument 'item'. I dont quite get why since I am already using "self" as the first argument in both functions.

Comment: my apologies.  I have edited the post to add the _button as an argument.  I also added the generic case of *args and **kwargs which is a good general tactic when you have errors like this. *args absorbs additional positional arguments and **kwargs absorbs any additonal keyword arguments that may be sent.  checkout Kivy event dispatcher documentation (help on bind()) and it may explain why extra arguments come through beyond what you explicitly sent.

Comment: Thank you! it finally worked. Been stuck on it for the past two days