# python solve got multiple values for argument when binding functions to dynamically created buttons

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy

I have this code which is suppose to create buttons dynamically based on items in a list, and then by clicking a button adding it to an external .txt.

I can create the buttons, but for some reason binding each button to an indiviual version of the writeFile() function does not work. I always get the error message "python solve got multiple values for argument 'item'", which confuses me quite bit since I am already using self as the first keyword in both function.

```
class MAIN(Screen):
items = ["Bike", "Car", "Boat", "Airplane"]                             
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)

        self.list_of_btns = []

    def writeFile(self, item):
        with open(f"./orders/TEST", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"\n-{item}")

    def create(self, list=items):                                               #Creates Categorie Buttons
        self.h = 1
        for i in list:
            self.h = self.h - 0.2
            _btn = Button(text= f"{i}", size_hint=(.2,.22), pos_hint={"center_y":self.h, "center_x":.5}) 
            add_fun = partial(self.writeFile, item=i)
            _btn.bind(on_press=add_fun)
            self.list_of_btns.append(_btn)   
            self.add_widget(_btn)
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I answered this in your other post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74677171/assigning-functions-to-dynamically-created-buttons-in-kivy
in my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `writeFile()` method should expect an argument that is the `Button` that was pressed. Try modifying the signature of that method to:

```
def writeFile(self, button, item):
```